# Actionscript 3.0 random number script not running

Tags: random, actionscript

Hello I am creating a simple game that asks questions. However I would like the questions to be randomed throughout the game.

So, there are 11 questions so I random a number between one and eleven

Then it would set an array value so that if the question has already been chosen it would not be chosen again.

Once it has randomed a value for a question that has not been asked it goes to that frame. (Using Adobe Flash)

So, simply:

Random number -> has this question been asked? -> Yes (restart script) -> No (Go to corresponding frame)

I have set up a code but for some reason it does not run. When I use "Stop();" it ignores it and keeps going through the frames. What is going on here? Can someone create a code for me that just works? I can read code just fine, but I fail at writing it. So I can change the frames where necessary.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep two arrays; one of all the questions, unmodified, and one that you choose the questions from, removing as you go. Something like:

```
var allQuestions:Array = ["...", "...", ...];
var questions:Array = [];

public function getRandomQuestion():String
{
    // if our questions are empty, fill them
    if( questions.length == 0 )
        this.fillQuestions();

    // choose a random question index
    var index:int = int( Math.random() * questions.length ); 

    // this will remove that question from the array and return it. The [0] at the end
    // is because splice returns an array, so we're returning the first value of 
    // it (i.e. the question we just removed)
    return questions.splice( index, 1 )[0];
}

public function fillQuestions():String
{
    // fill the questions array here from our full array
    for each( var s:String in allQuestions )
        questions.push( s );
}
```